# Find Integer using Matcher class

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to identify the number of an incoming email using Matcher class.

Email subject would be : `Pricing Approval : Engagement Id 510074136.`

I need to get the number alone (`5100743316`). How can I achieve that using Pattern and Matcher class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need the Matcher class for this, if you're only concerned with a single instance of numbers, as you could simply do this:

```
String myNumberString = emailMessage.Subject.replaceAll('\\D','');
```

String#replaceAll accepts a regex, and \\D indicates "non-digit characters", so this method effectively removes all the non-digits.

If you do want to use Pattern and Matcher, you certain can:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\d+');
Matcher m = p.matcher(emailMessage.Subject);
while(m.find()) {
    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(m.group(0));
}
```

This would find each consecutive set of numbers in the string.

Comment: Your first suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. It worked great. The only reason I thought I would need Matcher class is that I got the following error "The apex class emailHandler failed due to: System.LimitException: Regex too complicated" while I was testing with my previous code as I had as shown here.  for (string s : emailSubject.split('(?!^)')) {
            if (s.isNumeric()) {
                engagementId = engagementId + s;
            }
        } */

Comment: @user28452 The pattern/matcher class might have also complained, as there's a 1,000,000 iteration limit on matching, which it seems your regex somehow caused, although I'm not sure why off the top of my head. Some patterns are just not safe to use.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Thanks for the input. I went with the first solution.